# Creating new polygons from intersecting polygon and polylines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, intersection, overlapping-features, polygon-creation

I want to create new polygons from the intersecting polygon and polylines shown in the images below. At the output, I need to get four polygons representing the polygons shown in the top image after the polylines are overlaid onto the main polygon.

Any thoughts on how I can do this, please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) geoalgorithm.

Before:
[image: input]

After:
[image: output]

Afterwards the application of the ["Remove null geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#remove-null-geometries) and ["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries) geoalgorithms is recommended.